# Image not getting centered

Tags: html, css

I'm attempting to center an image above a div container. below is my HTML code.

```
 <div class="main-container">  
        <img class="ipl-img" src="assets/img/Indian_Premier_League_Official_Logo.svg.png">
    <div class="center">
        
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the css

```
.center {
margin-top: 20px;
margin-bottom: 10px;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
width: 90%;
padding: 10px;
height: 400px;
border-radius: 25px;
box-shadow: rgba(149, 157, 165, 0.2) 0px 8px 24px;
background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}

.ipl-img {
padding-right: 30px;
padding-top: 90px;
margin: auto;
width: 50%;
position: absolute;
left: 0px;
top: 0px;
z-index: 1;
}
```

Even though i have used margin auto i cannot seem to get the image centered. How can i get it centred?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add `top` `bottom` `right` `left` to `0` and `margin: auto;` to center an absolute element;

here the result:

```css
.center {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 90%;
  padding: 10px;
  height: 400px;
  border-radius: 25px;
  box-shadow: rgba(149, 157, 165, 0.2) 0px 8px 24px;
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}

.ipl-img {
  width: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
 <div class="main-container">  
   <div class="center">
        <img class="ipl-img" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTK2nG24AYDm6FOEC7jIfgubO96GbRso2Xshu1f8abSYQ&s"></img>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

HTML:

```
<div class="main-container">  
  <div class="center">
    <img class="ipl-img" src="assets/img/Indian_Premier_League_Official_Logo.svg.png">
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.center {

  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;

}
```

Comment: This works. But for what i'm trying to do further, this method kind of complicate things. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could simply use the  tag, right? It works when I use it.

```
<div class="main-container"> 
<center><img class="ipl-img" src="uploads/123.png"> </center>
    <div class="center">
    </div>
</div>
```

If you're using this code it will not working with your css code for class 'ipl-img'.

if you cann't run this then try this,

```
<div class="main-container"> 
<img class="ipl-img" src="uploads/123.png">
    <div class="center">
    </div>
</div>
```

and css code for 'ipl-img' class

```
.ipl-img {
    display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 50%;
}
```

Comment: The <center> tag is no longer valid in HTML5.

Answer (score 0):

with your code this is probably the easiest way to get what you want.  Never use absolute positioning unless you absolutely have to.  Just text-align:center on your top div and get rid of the abs

```css
.center {
margin-top: 20px;
margin-bottom: 10px;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
width: 90%;
padding: 10px;
height: 400px;
border-radius: 25px;
box-shadow: rgba(149, 157, 165, 0.2) 0px 8px 24px;
background-color: green;

}

.ipl-img {
padding-right: 30px;
padding-top: 90px;
margin: auto;
width: 50%;

z-index: 1;
}
.main-container{
text-align:center;}
```

```html
<div class="main-container">  
        <img class="ipl-img" src="https://via.placeholder.com/300">
    <div class="center">
        
    </div>
</div>
```